# How do I print the dimensions of a dataset (csv file) using Pandas- library and also print out some lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

So I am programming in Python 3, and would like to print out the dimensions of a dataset (csv file) using the pandas library dataframe, and also do a few other things that I dont quite grasp the idea of? this is just an example as I only need explanation on how.
Say I have 2 functions:

in func1 i have (supposedly) loaded a dataset using pandas:

def func1(a):

```
namesOfColumns = ["The sepal-length", "The sepal-width", "The petal-length", "The petal-width", "class"]

a = "some_file"

some_file = pd.read_csv(a)

return (some_file)
```

def func2(data):

```
#code for printing the dimensions of the dataset
#code for printing the top 3 lines
#code for printing the mean and standard variation of the sepal-width
#code for plot box plot of each attribute
```

Would someone explain how I can approach the steps in func2?

Comment: print dimensions: `a.shape`, print first n lines: `a.head(n)`, print std, mean: `df[column].std()`,`df[column].mean()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for printing the dimensions of the dataset:

```
print(data.info())  # Descriptive info about the DataFrame
print(data.shape)  # gives a tuple with the shape of DataFrame
```

Code for printing the top 3 lines:

```
print(data.head(3))
```

Print mean and standard variation of the sepal-width:

```
print(data.describe())  # General statistics
print(data['Sepal_Width'].mean(), data['Sepal_Width'].std())  # Mean & std dev of Sepal_Width only
```

Code for plot box plot of each attribute:

```
data.boxplot(namesOfColumns)
```